# ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' , returned status code -1:

Tags: git, jenkins

I am running Jenkins on windows and when I am trying to build my project through jenkins, the following error occurs:

```
git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress <url>Assist-Ops.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
 > git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from <url>
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:810)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1066)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)


at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress <URL>/Assist-Ops.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1719)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:808)
```

Started getting this error after I changed my password.
I have created new SSH key and added it to github repository.  I am able to clone the repository and build though command line.

```
    mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 2):

try to disable use of the git credential cache using `git config --global --unset credential.helper`. You may also need to do `git config --system --unset credential.helper` if this has been set in the system config file

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), you will find that `core.askpass` is not a boolean value but an external program that is used to ask you for a password. So setting this variable to `true` is not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was coming because I was using a string parameter **path** in my pipeline.

Renaming **path** to something else fixed it.