# Jenkins: ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm a relative novice with Jenkins and am trying to simply run a build from code stored on Bitbucket.  I am using git. I have setup the job source control as https protocol as:
  url: https://myaccount@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo.git
  credentials: username/password

the 'build' section points to the pom.xml in the root and runs the clean test maven goal

I have the Git plugin 2.5.2

I am running Jenkins as a Windows service (Windows 10).

The error on building the project is

```
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
```

> git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
>   ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://username@bitbucket.org/username/myrepo.git 
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:799)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1055)
>       at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1086)
>       at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
>       at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
>       at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
>   Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://username@bitbucket.org/username/myrepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:

Any advice welcome

Comment: It's highly possible git asks for password in spite of not being allowed to (non-interactive shell), and this is a private repo. You need to somehow provide the password some other way.

Comment: Are you able to ping bitbucket.org from a build step in your job?

Answer (score 4):

as I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43964812/908936 :

try to disable use of the git credential cache using

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

You may also need to do

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

if this has been set in the system config file

Comment: I had the same issue, tried running the above command, it happens only for one particular pr builder. any other solution pls

Answer (score -1):

Any specific reason for using username/password for accessing the repo?

Another way that is more convenient and secure is to use ssh.
Follow these steps:
If not already done, generate a rsa key in your Jenkins server for the user that you are using to access bitbucket.

```
sudo su <bitbucket user> #if such user not already created, create it first.  
ssh-keygen
```

Press enter for every question asked.

Now got to the hidden .ssh directory in home and copy the public key that you need to paste in bitbucket keys in next step.
    `vi ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Now login to the same bitbucket account and go to:   User Profile -> Setting -> Security -> SSH keys and paste here the public key copied in (2).
In your scripts and settings, replace the 'http' in your bitbucket url with 'ssh'

Now try again and it should work.

Comment: Please accept an answer if any one of them worked for you